# How do I wire Persistence layer into MVC application?

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller, zend-framework

Alternative Question Title:  **What is the path the data travels from its invocation inside persistence layer to its destination in the view?**

I am not very clear on how to get the data from persistence layer into view of my application.   I am looking for a good basic answer, if such exists, that involves instruction on navigating persistence layer placement within MVC, with some justification and good layer separation techniques, as needed.

I have been looking into this for a bit, and I have seen a few different approaches.  Also I am inching my way towards using Zend Framework 2, which does things in its own way.

Here is what I am dealing with:

**Actual Data Call (API method)**

I have to get the data out of the persistence layer somehow.  It can be SQL, DQL, ORM.  Somewhere I run the actual API that goes somewhere, gets me some data, and returns it in a form (array, object, etc).

```
//Example MySQL
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT Name FROM City LIMIT 10");

//Example Doctrine ORM
$q = $em->createQuery('SELECT c FROM \Entity\City c');
$result = $q->getArrayResult();
```

**Persistence Manager Object**

There is sometimes an extra hurdle aside form the actual API call to get the data.  It is "how to position persistence layer worker within the MVC".

```
//Example MySQL object
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

//Example ORM object
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
```

**Question:**

Where do I place the `object` and the `method` calls?  Exactly?

**Why not place both in View?**

I imagine placing them both in a View layer is bad (generally not advised), but then why not?

**Looking at ZF2 example**

How about placing them both into Controller, will that work?  In ZF2 it seems to be the norm to instantiate `object` in a Factory (which I understand to be part of the Controller), and then do a `method` call in Controller.  But is it the recommended way?

**How I seem to do it**

I have a legacy application that is slowly acquiring ZF2 practices but is not on ZF2 stack.  So for example I use some ZF2 modules.  I have set up a singleton that returns me the persistence `object`.  Once my app has initialized, I can call that object *anywhere* from within my application.  Controller, View, etc.  I usually call the `object` using a global invocation, i.e. `$em = Doctrine::getEntityManager()` in a method of my specific Controller class.

Then I call the API `method` that returns me the actual data in the same method of the Controller class.  Then I supply the data to my View layer, where my View is embedded into the Controller itself.

```
class Controller
{
    function reactToEventAction()
    {
        $em = Doctrine::getEntityManager();//singleton
        $result $em->getRepository('City')->findBy(array('name'=>$name));

        return ViewModel(array(
            'result' => $result
        ));
    }
}
```

The above is kind of a mix of Singleton pattern, MVC, and embedding View into Controller and ZF2 and my own app style.

I have heard criticism of such code separation in that ... View is embedded into Controller and layer separation is not independent.  i.e. View should somehow be *outside* of the Controller.  Perhaps.

How do I wire up persistence layer into the complexities of MVC layers?  Is there no "one way"?

Note:  Assume I am using both MySQL and ORM in my application because I do.   I am looking for a way to consistently wire up both of them correctly.